# How can I remove motion in continuous frame-to-frame subtraction with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction, infrared, pulse

**Background:**

Im pulsing an infrared IR LED on/off and capturing the images with an USB camera. For example: In the odd frames the LED is on and in the even frames the LED is off (I cant control in which frames it is on/off). Now Im subtracting the current frame with the last using cvAbsDiff. Usually only the LED signal remains in the image.

**Now the problem:**

When there is strong ambient light like it is coming from the sun, it creates a strong shadow. When I subtract the current frame with the last frame and move any object fast enough, this object is not at the same position in both frames. So the frame-to-frame subtraction will give me the edges of this moved object (the motion) and will interfere with the LED signal.

**How can I remove the "motion" from the resulting image and preserve the pulsing LED?**

Note: I tried using cvThreshold. The intensities between LED and the motion is almost the same.

Comment: for understanding: isnt the object motion a problem independently from sun/shadows etc? So is your question basically about motion compensation for frame-to-frame subtraction, or is there anything specific about IR LED, sun, shadow etc?

Comment: Yes its about motion compensation basically.